# Reshaping dataframe with multiple IDs

Tags: python, pandas

I need helo creating the format transformation:

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fiW5.png)

I have created pd.wide_to_long but I cannot find an example identical to mine?

Can you help?

Comment: please copy and paste the dataframe of image, don't show images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df.set_index(['City','Var']).rename_axis(columns='Year').stack().unstack('Var')
```

Comment: Thank you. I get the error: "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"
Can you help?

Comment: could you copy and paste your dataframe? I need it to make a solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples I need it to copy with `pd.read_clipboard`

Comment: You could copy an paste a example

Comment: There were dublicates in the ID - so that ex. all cities had var 1 twice. You code worked! However, when I run your code, some var disapear for some cities. Ex City A is missing Var 1 but not any other cities. Do you know why?

Comment: I should run it to know maybe you need sort with `DataFrame.sort_values`

Comment: The solution: df.set_index(['City','Var']).rename_axis(columns='Year').stack(dropna = False).unstack('Var')